# Bootstrap datetimepicker not working in Rails 4.2.5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm using rails 4.2.5.
I need to pick a date and time slot for booking an apartment for my rails app.
So i did a small search and i found this gem which takes care of my needs,
https://github.com/TrevorS/bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails
I did everything mentioned in the readme.
I used the following code in my bookings page for the user to pick the date and time slot :`<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>`

But it doest work. When i check the console of my browser I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function"
What is wrong here? All the required js files and css files were getting included,still its not working!
I tried a couple of other gems too,using them also i'm getting the same error telling me that datetimepicker is not a function.
What should i do?

Comment: Check the source of the page - is the js code for it being included?

Comment: Yes,Is there any other stuff that i'm missing?

Comment: did you restart server?

Comment: Yes!
Is there any other method that i could try?

Comment: The response to this question shows how Rails is dying.  In my experience, the procedure outlined in all of the "gem" ways to do this do not work.  I've tried 3 different ones with incomplete / non-working instructions.  Given non-maintained state of Rails-gems for this critical functionality, it appears the only way to do this is to manually include all the js and css (start with everything inline, in case the 'pipeline' is the issue).  Oh, and start learning Node in your spare time, if you have any "spare" time left, after re-inventing the wheel all day, given no blueprints available.